# What system exports the PATH environment variable?

Tags: startup, environment-variables

I'm trying to track down [this bug I just noticed on PythonAnywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/29601/) where the `PATH` environment variable isn't marked for export when running `~/.profile`, and I'd like to know what system is normally responsible for exporting it.

I read the [EnvironmentVariables wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables), which seems to indicate that the default **value** is read from `/etc/environment`, but it doesn't say what system actually reads it and exports it.

I looked at a bunch of system config files like `/etc/profile` and all of `/etc/profile.d/*.sh`, but didn't see anything related to exporting, `PATH`, or `/etc/environment`.

I'm using a 16.04 image on PythonAnywhere, and 18.04 on my desktop, which doesn't have the same problem.

Comment: Are you using systemd? These https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.environment-generator.html ?

Comment: @Rinzwind Apparently. `/sbin/init` is a symlink to `/lib/systemd/systemd`

Comment: @Rinzwind Oh, actually, maybe it's not that simple. PID 1 is Bash. I'm following the instructions [here](https://superuser.com/a/1018046/4435640).

Comment: If /sbin/init says systemd it is systemd ;-)

Comment: @Rinzwind What should I be looking for? On PythonAnywhere, there are no generators. On my desktop I have `/usr/lib/systemd/user-environment-generators/30-systemd-environment-d-generator`, but it's an ELF file. I tried running `strings` on it but I'm not sure if there's anything relevant except `/etc/environment.d`.

Comment: `/etc/environment` is read by PAM. See `man pam_env`